# Доступ к элементу через $this

Tags: php, jquery

Всем привет. Есть такая верстка

```
<div class="row align-items-center cover" data-id="<?echo $item['id'];?>">
   <div class="col-6">
      <div class="inputblock">
         <div class="icon text"></div>
         <input class="input-text" value="<?echo $item['text']?>" name="text" type="text" 
         required="required">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Как получить значение val input следующего за .text, нужно через This, т.к. эти блоки повторяются.
Пробуй вот так не срабатывает.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemInput = '.input-text'; 
    var itemDel = $('.text');
    itemDel.click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $thisInput = $this.closest(itemInput);
        console.log($thisInput.val);
    });
 });
```

Comment: и зачем вам `var itemInput` ? чтобы переменных и кода было ппобольше?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых не `closest`, а `next`. Во-вторых: не `val`, а `val()`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var itemInput = '.input-text'; 
    var itemDel = $('.text');
    itemDel.click(function(e){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $thisInput = $this.next(itemInput);
        console.log($thisInput.val());
    });
 });
```

```css
.icon.text {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row align-items-center cover" data-id="<?echo $item['id'];?>">
   <div class="col-6">
      <div class="inputblock">
         <div class="icon text"></div>
         <input class="input-text" value="<?echo $item['text']?>" name="text" type="text" 
         required="required">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```